# Native Client(NACI) can invoke a third-party DLL file?

Tags: google-nativeclient

I want to know that Native Client(NACI) can invoke a third-party DLL file?

Answer (score 0):

No, Native Client is a platform-agnostic application sandbox. This means that you can never access platform-specific libraries, such as a Windows DLL.

That being said, Native Client does support shared libraries in some cases, but they must be compiled with the Native Client toolchain. See https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/dynamic-loading for more information.